# WASP scanner communication with IPhone

Tags: iphone, barcode-scanner, core-bluetooth

I have created an iphone application, which gets the barcode value from the WASP scanner and do some logic.

I need to know is there any call back methods available in iPhone SDK so that we know the scanning is done in WASP?

Please help.

Thanks,
Bharathi

Comment: Maybe a notification of a characteristic ? (since it's tagged CoreBluetooth, aka iOS framework for Bluetooth Low-Energy).

Comment: I am handling the call back methods for the Core bluetooth.. But those callback are not calling for the WASP Scanner. But The WASP scanner by default displayin the scanned code in my app, with out interacting to any method.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the WASP scanner shows up in the default Bluetooth menu in the iOS Settings app? In this case, it probably advertises itself as a keyboard and simply inputs what it scans as a sequence of keystrokes. There's no way to intercept this with CoreBluetooth - maybe you can set the focus to an invisible text field and use an observer to detect when text has been entered into this field.